# Ionic app connection to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ionic-framework

Basically I have a mobile app that I am building in Ionic (3 I believe). I have a website that I built a while back in C# using Visual Studio. The site is attached to a SQL Server database. This Ionic app I am creating is to go along with said website.

My question is how do I connect my app to the same database. I'm very new to Ionic and I cannot seem to find any answers online. I have found some vague SQLite stuff but that is about it.

Not necessarily looking for specific answers in code (although I wouldn't say no). If someone could even breakdown the steps I'd need to take then I can go and research it myself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had a quick read and google about ionic. If it is a client side javascript library then the only way to get data from a database is to write an external web service that does all of this for you and call the web service from ionic. This is what makes me think that - this example uses an external PHP app to provide a web service that converts data to JSON (which is consumed by ioninc) https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-connect-database-sql-server-in-ionic/54881

Comment: I'm reading HTML, JS, Angular etc. so I'm pretty sure this is a client side JS library so I think you'll need to write a web service in a server side language like ASP.Net C#. This might help get you started on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to mysql database with your ionic app using Webservice in c#.There is no need of SQLite for connecting  your app to sql database.It can be used as local storage instead.Ionic use json data to access.So the data you retrieve from Webservice must be Json.

Answer (score 0):

It depends
Do you wish to directly access SQL database from your ionic app or you want to have access to the database via api.
1. Directly connect to SQL database from ionic application using Cordova plugin.
Follow this link for more info -[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlserver)